# Assign List to itself concatenated with another list

Tags: c#, concatenation

Why does this work

```
this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = null;
this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList());
```

yet this gives me the error below

```
MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl =  MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList());
```

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: You need to convert the result of `Concat` to a list with `ToList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `ToList` with `Where` because [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `IEnumerable<TSource>` as parameter (which is the returning type of `Where`, no need for convert to `List<TSource>`), instead use it end of your statement and convert returning result to `List<T>` which is `IEnumerable<T>`

```
MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add")).ToList();
```

That is working because the type of `DataSource` is `object` most likely.Therefore that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T> or any other type.`

```
this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList());
```